# Prepend "number," to each line, where number is calculated from nth term

Tags: substitute, line-numbers

I have a file with 48 lines like

```
0.00000
0.00621
0.16298
0.19977
0.40198
0.29450
0.49277
0.28054
0.43256
0.18729
0.28934
```

And I want to prepend `d.ddddddd,` to each line, each `d` represents a digit (so the calculation should be rounded).

The number prepended is calculated as `n/48000` where `n` is the greatest integer less than the line number (0-indexed, the first line should have 0 prepended)

It should end up looking like

```
0.0000000,0.00000
0.0000208,0.00621
0.0000417,0.16298
0.0000625,0.19977
0.0000833,0.40198
0.0001042,0.29450
```

and so on.

Comment: Maybe you should show us what you tried before so that people don't have to do all of the job but simply help you with the substitution which causes you a problem. Also, I'm not sure vim is really the best tool for what you are trying to do: maybe `awk` or a simple python script would be a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, I understand exactly want you are trying to achieve. But given your test data, I came up with the following substitution:

`:%s#.*#\=printf("%.07f,%s", ((line('.')-1)/48000.0), submatch(0))`

Which uses the substitution command and prepends the result of (dividing line number -1, `(line('.')-1)`) by 48000 to each line and formats it to 7 digits.

This needs a vim with `+float` feature.